# MySQL Workbench - how to search all columns in every table

Tags: mysql-workbench

In [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=466698) how do I search for a column which can be located in any schema. Basically I'm looking for a column called "notification" and I want to search all schemas for that column.

Look at this screenshot where I know for a fact there is a column named "activated_at" yet when I search for it after highlighting all my tables (using select all command also) it finds nothing. Why?

but if I run the following query its able to find the column, so why not with GUI?

```
    SELECT 
    table_schema,
    table_name, 
    column_name, 
    data_type,
    ordinal_position

FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 

WHERE column_name = 'activated_at' ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a new `Query` tab - from the `File` menu option choose the `New Query` item (second one down).

Then, it's exactly the same as in the MySQL tool.

```
use information_schema;
show tables;
SELECT * FROM columns;
```

will give the result:

```
Tables_in_information_schema
-----------------------------
CHARACTER_SETS
COLLATIONS
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
COLUMNS                                <<--
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
..
<more columns snipped>
..
```

For some reason, the `information_schema` database doesn't appear in the 
databases list in the GUI, but if you explicitly 'use' it, it will work.

Et voilà

Answer (score 2):

If you know `database name`, you can find the column name using `workbench GUI`:

1. Right click on the `database name` and select `Schema Inspector`:

[image]
 2. Select `Columns` tab on the header. There you will find all the column details with table name.

[image]

If you want to search in all the databases, then you may use `information_schema.columns`

```
 desc information_schema.columns;
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_CATALOG            | varchar(512)        | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA             | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME               | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLUMN_NAME              | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| ORDINAL_POSITION         | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| COLUMN_DEFAULT           | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IS_NULLABLE              | varchar(3)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| DATA_TYPE                | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH   | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUMERIC_PRECISION        | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUMERIC_SCALE            | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DATETIME_PRECISION       | bigint(21) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CHARACTER_SET_NAME       | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLLATION_NAME           | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_TYPE              | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_KEY               | varchar(3)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| EXTRA                    | varchar(30)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| PRIVILEGES               | varchar(80)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLUMN_COMMENT           | varchar(1024)       | NO   |     |         |       |
| GENERATION_EXPRESSION    | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
21 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

Use this query to find the column `notification`, this will give you database name, table name and column name.

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%notification%';
```

I hope this will help you!!